# Error compiling C++ source utilizing the Boost.Math library

Tags: c++, macos, boost, g++

I'm trying to use a couple of functions from the Boost Math library in some C++ code using the G++ compiler but I've been unsuccessful. This is on macOS.

I downloaded and extracted the Boost `tar.gz` from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.63.0/) and placed it into my source folder.

Within my C++ I've tried

`#include "boost_1_63_0/boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp"` and

`#include <boost_1_63_0/boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp>`.

The quotation version partially works but the `chi_squared.hpp` file includes `fwd.hpp` using the bracket (`#include <...>`) notation and that breaks my compilation with error `In file included from main.cpp:9: ./boost_1_63_0/boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp:12:10: fatal error: 'boost/math/distributions/fwd.hpp' file not found #include <boost/math/distributions/fwd.hpp>`.

To compile I've used an assortment of commands, all unsuccessfully:

`g++ -L /boost_1_63_0/boost/math/distributions main.cpp`

`g++ -I"/boost_1_63_0/boost/math/" main.cpp`

`g++ -I "/boost_1_63_0/boost/math/" main.cpp`

`g++ main.cpp -lboost_math`

What is the correct include statement and G++ command that I need to use?

Comment: Try `-I/boost_1_63_0/`. Do not mention boost_1_63_0 in the source code, only in the compilation flags.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. all of the boost code is in the `boost_1_63_0` directory so I was just listing the full path. Chopping it down to `#include "boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp"` paired with `g++ -I/boost_1_63_0/ main.cpp` yields `fatal error: boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp' file not found`

Comment: What is the **full** path to chi_squared.hpp?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. from the directory containing my CPP source, the path is `boost_1_63_0/boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp`. G++ seems to be able to find `chi_squared.hpp` just fine when I use the full path using the quotation include notation. The problem is that `chi_squared.hpp` includes others files with the bracket notation and those includes seem to be the issue.

Comment: A full or absolute path starts from the root of the filesystem, not from any random directory within it. Most people use absolute paths in their command lines. If you prefer to use a relative path instead, then you must (1) drop the leading `/` and (2) make sure it starts from the **current working directory** rather than any directory that contains the source.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. still no luck, my include has the absolute path `#include "/Users/[me]/[project_dir]/boost_1_63_0/boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp"` and my g++ command is `g++ -I/Users/[me]/[project_dir]/boost_1_63_0/boost/math/distributions/ main.cpp`. Still getting same error: `In file included from main.cpp:8:
/Users/[me]/[project_dir]/boost_1_63_0/boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp:12:10: fatal error: 
      'boost/math/distributions/fwd.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/math/distributions/fwd.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Just got it to work. Adding resolution now. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using

`#include "/Users/[me]/[project_dir]/boost_1_63_0/boost/math/distributions/chi_squared.hpp"`

and

`g++ -I/Users/[me]/[project_dir]/boost_1_63_0/ main.cpp`